# Why does laravel \Storage::store method cause this error?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

In my local environment why I do following, it works.

```
    if( $request->file ){

        $path = $request->file('file')->store('public/chat/files');

        $mime_type = $request->file('file')->getMimeType(); 


        if( strstr( $mime_type, 'video' ) ){
            $data['message_type'] = 'video';
        }else if( strstr( $mime_type, 'image' ) ){
            $data['message_type'] = 'image';
        }else if( strstr( $mime_type, 'audio' ) ){
            $data['message_type'] = 'audio';
        }
```

But on apache running on Digital Ocean droplet when I run the same code I get the following error.

```
[2019-02-26 11:45:48] local.ERROR: The file "" does not exist {"userId":3,"email":"user@user.com","exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\File\\Exception\\FileNotFoundException(code: 0): 
The file \"\" does not exist a$
[stacktrace]
#0 /var/www/html/plugin_love_api/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/File/File.php(79): Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\File\\MimeType\\MimeTypeGuesser->guess('')
#1 /var/www/html/plugin_love_api/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/File/File.php(58): Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\File\\File->getMimeType()
#2 /var/www/html/plugin_love_api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/FileHelpers.php(60): Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\File\\File->guessExtension()
#3 /var/www/html/plugin_love_api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/UploadedFile.php(35): Illuminate\\Http\\UploadedFile->hashName()
#4 /var/www/html/plugin_love_api/app/Http/Controllers/ChatController.php(71): Illuminate\\Http\\UploadedFile->store('public/chat/fil...')
#5 [internal function]: App\\Http\\Controllers\\ChatController->sendMessage(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#6 /var/www/html/plugin_love_api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php(54): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#7 /var/www/html/plugin_love_api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(45): Illuminate\\Routing\\Controller->callAction('sendMessage', Array)
#8 /var/www/html/plugin_love_api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(219): Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route), Object(App\\Http\\Controllers\\ChatController), 'se$
#9 /var/www/html/plugin_love_api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(176): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->runController()
#10
```

**PHP version is : PHP 7.2.15-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 (cli) (built: Feb  8 2019 14:54:22) ( NTS )**

Also I have set **777** permissions on `storage` folder and all it's descendants.

### UPDATE:

This seems to be the issue with the size of file that I am uploading.

it does not work with more than 2MB but works with ~6kb file.

Comment: Are u using apache server?

Comment: @Md.AbuZaman Yes

Comment: It's a very common problem in laravel with apache. Try nginx server.

Comment: @Md.AbuZaman Please have a look I have updated question.

Comment: Did u set the file size? You can set size like `'image_file_input_name' => 'required|mimes:jpeg,bmp,png|size:5000',` also u can increase your max file size from php.ini

Answer (score 0):

So first I would check that the form is using

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

If you are using Laravel Forge make sure the file limit is set to something acceptable, this can be changed under "server details -> PHP"

[image]

You could also check by using dd on the request and checking what you are receiving on the server side